# how to export all databases as separate sql files instead of localhost.sql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to export all databases as separate .sql files but I get localhost.sql Can anyone here show me how we can accomplish this?

Comment: It's good to tell people what you have done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Log into phpMyAdmin.
2. Select the source database on the left pane.
3. Click on the Export tab in the top center pane.
4. On the next page you must select a Quick or Custom export method. ...
5. From the dropdown menu, choose the format you'd like to save the file as. ...
6. Click the Go button to continue.
7. A pop-up displays allowing you to download the file. (Note: your browser may also download it automatically.)

For more check [Check this steps](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214395738-phpMyAdmin-How-to-backup-or-export-a-database-or-table) Maybe you should probably be searching well on Google

Comment: Thanks Ebinto for the steps. I got it.

Comment: This does NOT provide a solution or even an answer to the question and should NOT be marked as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > alldb.sql
```

Look up the documentation for mysqldump. You may want to use some of the options mentioned in comments:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt --all-databases > alldb.sql

mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases --skip-lock-tables > alldb.sql
```

Comment: Waruna thanks so much. It is accomplished exactly using console as per your source codes.